# Jmeter VIEWSTATE Dynamic

Tags: xpath, jmeter, element

I am trying to catch the element "VIEWSTATE".
I am able to catch the "VIEWSTATE" on the first page, but not on the next.
On next page, the element is dynamic.

How do I catch the viewstate Dynamic element on the second page?

See images below:

The first page
[image]
The second page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that your login fails, most probably due to missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager).

Also be aware that JMeter's Post-Processors follow [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so moving the extractors to be the children of the relevant requests could also be a reason as sub-samples may not contain the dynamic parameters you are looking for and variables extracted from main sample are simply being overwritten by the sub-samples.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for example .NET based web application login test plan.